# External Content with Groovy BuilderSupport

Tags: groovy, builder

I've built a custom builder in Groovy by extending BuilderSupport. It works well when configured like nearly every builder code sample out there:

```
def builder = new MyBuilder()
builder.foo {
    "Some Entry" (property1:value1, property2: value2)
}
```

This, of course, works perfectly. The problem is that I don't want the information I'm building to be in the code. I want to have this information in a file somewhere that is read in and built into objects by the builder. I cannot figure out how to do this.

I can't even make this work by moving the simple entry around in the code.
This works:

```
def textClosure = { "Some Entry" (property1:value1, property2: value2) }
builder.foo(textClosure)
```

because textClosure is a closure.

If I do this:

```
def text = '"Some Entry" (property1:value1, property2: value2)'
def textClosure = { text }
builder.foo(textClosure)
```

the builder only gets called for the "foo" node. I've tried many variants of this, including passing the text block directly into the builder without wrapping it in a closure. They all yield the same result.

Is there some way I take a piece of arbitrary text and pass it into my builder so that it will be able to correctly parse and build it?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that a String is not Groovy code. The way `ConfigSlurper` handles this is to compile the text into an instance of `Script` using `GroovyClassLoader#parseClass`. e.g.,

```
// create a Binding subclass that delegates to the builder
class MyBinding extends Binding {
    def builder
    Object getVariable(String name) {
        return { Object... args ->  builder.invokeMethod(name,args) }
    }   
}

// parse the script and run it against the builder
new File("foo.groovy").withInputStream { input ->
    Script s = new GroovyClassLoader().parseClass(input).newInstance()
    s.binding = new MyBinding(builder:builder)
    s.run()
}
```

The subclass of [Binding](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html) simply returns a closure for all variables that delegates the call to the builder. So assuming foo.groovy contains:

```
foo {
    "Some Entry" (property1:value1, property2: value2)
}
```

It would be equivalent to your code above.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you described is better solved with a slurper or parser.

See:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlParser

for XML based examples.

In your case. Given the XML file:

```
<foo>
    <entry name='Some Entry' property1="value1" property2="value2"/>
</foo>
```

You could slurp it with:

```
def text = new File("test.xml").text
def foo = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)
def allEntries = foo.entry
allEntries.each { 
    println it.@name
    println it.@property1
    println it.@property2
}
```

Comment: These examples still assume that the content to be parsed/slurped is in the classpath, which won't be the case for my application. I don't want to use XML for my configuration - I looked at the source for both the XmlSlurper and XmlParser and they're both very XML specific. I would have to write my slurper/parser from scratch because there's no common base like there is for BuilderSupport.

Comment: Seams I didn't get you problem. I added an example to clarify what I meant. Maybe you can point out what is the problem with that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Originally, I wanted to be able to specify

```
"Some Entry" (property1:value1, property2: value2)
```

in an external file. I'm specifically trying to avoid XML and XML-like syntax to make these files easier for regular users to create and modify. My current solution uses `ConfigSlurper` and the file now looks like:

```
"Some Entry"
{ 
   property1 = value1 
   property2 = value2 
}
```

`ConfigSlurper` gives me a map like this:

```
["Some Entry":[property1:value1,property2:value2]]
```

It's pretty simple to use these values to create my objects, especially since I can just pass the property/value map into the constructor.